# Create Code Snippets for All Projects in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, code-snippets, xcode10, xcode11

Is it possible to have code snippets that I can create one time and I can use for all new projects instead of creating the same ones all the time again ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Xcode code snippets you create are available to all projects by default.

From the Xcode Help article "Create and use code snippets" this is how to create one:

> In the source editor, select the code fragment you want to make into a snippet,
> then choose Editor > Create Code Snippet.
>
> Alternative, just choose Editor > Create Code Snippet.